Prove that $\int _Xf_ngd\mu \overset{n\to\infty}{\to}\int _Xfgd\mu$ ,$\forall g\in \mathcal{L}^\infty (\mu )$ if it's true $\forall g\in C_b(X)$
Let $X$ be a Polish space and $\mu :\mathfrak{B}_X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a finite measure on the Borel subsets of $X$. Suppose $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu )$ and $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu )$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _Xf_ngd\mu =\int _Xfgd\mu $ for all $g\in C_b(X)$ (continuous and bounded), can we conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _Xf_ngd\mu =\int _Xfgd\mu $ for all $g\in \mathcal{L}^\infty (\mu )$?

Using the 4.4.6 Theorem of the book "Measure Theory" (by V.I. Bogachev) and the Theorem 6.3.2 of the book "Integration and Modern Analysis" (by Benedetto and Czaja), we can conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _Xf_ngd\mu =\int _Xfgd\mu $, $\forall g\in \mathcal{L}^\infty (\mu )$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _Bf_nd\mu =\int _Bfd\mu $, $\forall B\in\mathfrak{B}_X$.
But I don't know how to prove previous limit. Also I wasn't able to find any counterexample.

I am pretty sure this is not true for two reasons: a) $C_b$ is not dense in $L_\infty$ and b)  the condition $\int f_n g \to \int f g$ for $g \in C_b$ does not imply that $f_n$ is bounded, whereas  the latter condition, $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L_1$, does.

The claim is false. Notice that $$\int f_n g \to \int fg , \quad \forall g \in C_b(X) \tag{1}$$  does not imply that $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L_1$, where as
$$\int f_n g \to \int fg , \quad \forall g \in L_\infty(X) \tag{2}$$  does (since this is tantamount to weak convergence in $L_1$). One can therefore construct an unbounded sequence such that $(1)$ holds but $(2)$ does not.

Moreover, since $C_b$ is not dense in $L_\infty$, one should  expect that, even in the case where $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L_1$, $(1)$ does not imply $(2)$. Here is a counterexample:
Consider $X=[-1,1]$. Let $f \in L_1(\mathbb R)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} f (x) dx =0$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx >0$. Set $f_n(x) = n f(nx)$ for $x \in [-1,1]$.  Then $(f_n)$ is bounded since
$$\int_{-1}^1 |f_n| = \int_{\mathbb R} |f| ,\quad n \ge 1$$
and:

$\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x) g(x) dx \to 0$ for ever $g \in C(X)=C_b(X)$.

Ineed, fix such $g$ and check that
$$ \begin{align} \int_{-1}^1 f_n (x)g (x) dx &= \int_{-1}^1 n f(nx) g(x) dx = \int_{-n}^n f(x) g(x/n) dx  \\&= \int_{-n}^n f(x) (g(x/n)-g(0) dx + g(0) \int_{-n}^n f(x) dx
\end{align} $$
the first integral converges to zero by DCT and the second one converges to $\int_{\mathbb R} f =0$.

It is not true that $\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x) g(x) dx \to 0$ for every $ g\in L_\infty(-1,1)$.

Indeed, take $g=1_{(0,1)}$. Then $$\int_{-1}^1 f_n g = \int_{0}^1 n f(nx) dx = \int_0^n f(x) dx \to \int_0^\infty f(x) dx >0 .$$
Bonus: Notice that $(f_n)$ is not uniformly integrable: Let $ε_0 = \int_0^\infty f>0$ and notice that for every $δ>0$
$$\int _0^δ |f_n(x)| dx= \int_{0}^{nδ} |f(x)| dx \to \int_0^\infty |f(x)| dx = ε_0.$$
This should come to no surprise since Dunford-Pettis theorem characterizes weakly compact subsets of $L_1$ via uniform integrability.
